# PHP When i click on button it shows next theorem from database

Tags: php, database

I got my first theorem working on the web but when I click on one of the buttons I want it shows the next theorem.

`PHP`

```
<?php
  echo" <button class='true'>true</button><textarea type='text' disabled>";
  $query = "SELECT `sText` FROM statement WHERE `sID` ='1'";

  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
  {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['sText'];
  }

  echo "</textarea><button class='false'>false</button>";
?>
```

Comment: You mean next record?

Comment: yeah i do my bad

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a link temporarily. If you want to use button, prolly you need to add a javascript to redirect when you click. So link is easier for now.

```
// your current id
$id = @$_GET['id'] ?: 1;

// get the next id
$nextIDQuery = "SELECT `sID` FROM statement WHERE `sID` >'".(int)$id."' limit 1";
// then fetch it as $nextID

// then change your current query to
$query = "SELECT `sText` FROM statement WHERE `sID` ='".(int)$id."'";

// your next link will be
echo "<a href='youfile.php?id=$nextID'>Next</a>";
```

Hope this can help you understand the logic.

Welcome to PHP.